# Allow negative decimal numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a  validation function that allows only 2 decimal places not more than that.But currently its not accepting negative numbers.Below is my code.How do I allow both negative and positive numbers with only upto 2 decimal places?

```
  function twodecimalplace(e) {
    var val = this.value;
    var re = /^([0-9]+[\.]?[0-9]?[0-9]?|[0-9]+)$/g;
    var re1 = /^([0-9]+[\.]?[0-9]?[0-9]?|[0-9]+)/g;
    if (re.test(val)) {
        //do something here

    } else {
        val = re1.exec(val);
        if (val) {
            this.value = val[0];
        } else {
            this.value = "";
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Why not using js `toFixed()` method???

Comment: If there are more there two decimal places, what are you going to do ? Throw error or you will skip it ?

Comment: @A.Wolff The same thing i was about to suggest :)

Comment: If there are more than two i am discarding them.Not allowing user to write.

Comment: @VigneswaranMarimuthu I'll be skipping it.The function does it all.It only needs modification to allow negative numbers

Answer (score 0):

This regex matches negative numbers too :

```
/^-?\d+(\.\d{0,2})?$/
```

- `-?` matches "-" or nothing (for positive and negative numbers)
- `\d+` one or more digits
- `(\.\d{0,2})?` matches a dot "." plus zero to two digits or nothing at all (to allow decimal)